# BigDecimal Problem in java

Tags: java, bigdecimal

```
BigDecimal bd= new BigDecimal("00.0000000000");
//now bd format to 0E-10
if(BigDecimal.ZERO.equals(bd) || bd.equals("0E-10"))
{
 flag=true; 
}
```

There are two problems in the above code

1. why variable **bd** automatically format to **0E-10**
2. **if** condition results false value, ie it does not enter inside **if** block.

Can anyone suggest. thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You've given the constructor ten digits after the decimal point, so even though all of them are zero, `BigDecimal` has decided to set its internal `scale` to 10. This explains the `-10` in `"0E-10"`.

As to `equals`, the [Javadoc says](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29):

> Compares this `BigDecimal` with the specified `Object` for equality.
>   Unlike `compareTo`, this method considers two `BigDecimal` objects equal
>   **only if they are equal in value and scale (thus 2.0 is not equal to
>   2.00 when compared by this method).**

Bottom line:

1. Use [`compareTo()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#compareTo%28java.math.BigDecimal%29) instead of `equals()`.
2. Don't directly compare `BigDecimal` to `String` as this won't work.

Answer (score 7):

You can test for zero using

```
bd.signum() == 0
```

`BigDecimal.equals` also includes scale (which is 10 in your case) and thus fails. In general you should use `compareTo` in order to compare `BigDecimals`.

Answer (score 1):

The BigDecimal uses a scale of 10 because you've given it ten digits after the decimal point, which answers your first point.

For the if, for the first part, you are comparing 0 with 00.00000000000 (the scale is different, so they aren't the same). In the second, you're comparing a String with a BigDecimal. Which won't work.